# (Javascript)Problems pushing array data in List

Tags: javascript

Here's my code.

```js
let mapOptions = []
let mapOption = {}

let averagelist=[1,2]

   for(let i=0; i<averagelist.length; i++){

         mapOption.center = averagelist[i]

         mapOption.level = 3

         mapOptions.push(mapOption)

         console.log(mapOptions)
     }
```

In the Snippet the result comes like strange so I'll tell you what I got.
From that code I wanted to get `mapOptions=[{"center":1,"level":3},{"center":2,"level":3}]`
But the result comes like mapOptions=`[{"center":2,"level":3},{"center":2,"level":3}]`
Where did the 1 go? I tried lots of things but can't solve this.
Could anybody help me? The browser I'm using is Chrome.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into the answer I added ? I hope it will work as per your expectation.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer if it helps so that it will be helpful for other fellow developers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code is not working as you are updating the object properties values which are primitive, Which results not updating the reference of the original object but only updating the values.

To make it work, you should reassign the whole object.

Working demo as per your code **:**

```js
let mapOptions = []
let mapOption = {}

let averagelist = [1, 2];

for(let i=0; i< averagelist.length; i++){
  mapOption = {center: averagelist[i], level: 3}
  mapOptions.push(mapOption)
}

console.log(mapOptions)
```

Demo with optimal solution **:**

```js
let averagelist = [1, 2];

const mapOptions = averagelist.map(item => ({center: item, level: 3}))

console.log(mapOptions)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let averagelist = [1,2];
let mapOptions = averagelist.map(i=>({center: i, level: 3}));
console.log(mapOptions);
```

Comment: ThankYou!!, Could I ask you another question? Why is my first code didn't work?

Comment: @menw because `let mapOption = {}` should have been declared as the first line inside the for loop. In your code, you were placing the same mapOption object again and again into the  `mapOptions` array, and so when you changed the `center` property, it was being changed in the same object that appeared multiple times in the array

Comment: Objects in JS are copied using reference. So you are pushing same pointer values in array but with different values. Which means, you are changing value at give address

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `let mapOption = {}` inside `for` block,for your question `mapOption` is defined as a global variable,so it will show the value last time it set.

```js
let mapOptions = []

let averagelist=[1,2]

for(let i=0; i<averagelist.length; i++){
     let mapOption = {}
     mapOption.center = averagelist[i]

     mapOption.level = 3

     mapOptions.push(mapOption)
 }
console.log(mapOptions)
```